# Validation loss not decreasing using dense layers altough training and validation data have the same distribution

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I have a problem that I have great difficulties understanding the concept that leads to these results. I use a keras dense layer to map 13 input features to 3 output labels. During the training, the loss (RMSE) for the training data constantly decreases even after 2000 epochs. However, the loss for the validation data does not decrease any more after some 200 epochs as you can see in the figure.

[image]

Now the thing that I don't understand at all is how you can explain this outcome given that the training and validation data have (almost) exactly the same distribution for all of the 13 input features and the 3 output labels. They are drawn from the very same distribution. To illustrate that I have plotted the histograms for some input features and output labels (and the kernel density functions) as you can see here:

[image]
[image]

If you want to see the histograms for all input features and output labels you can find them here (in all the distribution of the trai, valid and test dataset look quite similar): https://filetransfer.io/data-package/nHxgDfvF#link

Also I calculated the correlation between each of the input features and the output labels for the training, validation and test dataset and the values are almost the same across the datasets for all combinations. If wou want to the see values you can find them here: https://filetransfer.io/data-package/iVruYbLx#link. This just further highlights, that the training and validation data have the same distribution.

Here you can find my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_percentage_error
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import BatchNormalization, Dense, Flatten
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

#Read data from  csv files
ANN_input_data_features = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/User1/Desktop/TestDataANN_InputFeatures.csv", sep=';')
ANN_input_data_labels = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/User1/Desktop/TestDataANN_OutputLabels.csv", sep=';')
ANN_input_data_features = ANN_input_data_features.values
ANN_input_data_labels = ANN_input_data_labels.values

            
# standardize input features X and output labels Y
scaler_standardized_X = StandardScaler()
ANN_input_data_features = scaler_standardized_X.fit_transform(ANN_input_data_features)

scaler_standardized_Y = StandardScaler()
ANN_input_data_labels = scaler_standardized_Y.fit_transform(ANN_input_data_labels)


#Split dataset into train, validation, an test
index_X_Train_End = int(0.7 * len(ANN_input_data_features))
index_X_Validation_End = int(0.9 * len(ANN_input_data_features))

X_train = ANN_input_data_features [0: index_X_Train_End]
X_valid = ANN_input_data_features [index_X_Train_End: index_X_Validation_End]
X_test = ANN_input_data_features [index_X_Validation_End:]

Y_train = ANN_input_data_labels [0: index_X_Train_End]
Y_valid = ANN_input_data_labels [index_X_Train_End: index_X_Validation_End]
Y_test = ANN_input_data_labels [index_X_Validation_End:]


#Train the model
optimizer_adam = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate= 0.001)

numberOfInputFeatures = len(ANN_input_data_features[0])
numberOfOutputNeurons = len(ANN_input_data_labels[0])

model = keras.Sequential([
    Flatten(input_shape=(numberOfInputFeatures,)),
    Dense(30, activation='relu'),
    #BatchNormalization(axis = 1),
    Dense(50, activation='relu'),
    #BatchNormalization(axis = 1),
    Dense(50, activation='relu'),
    #BatchNormalization(axis = 1),
    Dense(30, activation='relu'),

    keras.layers.Dense(numberOfOutputNeurons)])

entireFolderNameForTheResultsOfTheRun = "C:/Users/User1/Desktop/Training/"
pathOfTheFileForBestModel = entireFolderNameForTheResultsOfTheRun + "bestModelSingleTimeSlotTest.keras"
callbacks = [  keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(pathOfTheFileForBestModel,  save_best_only=True) ]

model.compile(loss="mean_squared_error", optimizer=optimizer_adam, metrics=['mean_absolute_percentage_error'])
history = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=2000, batch_size=10, validation_data=(X_valid, Y_valid), callbacks=callbacks)

# Predict the values from the test dataset
model = keras.models.load_model(pathOfTheFileForBestModel)
Y_pred = model.predict(X_test)

# Rescale the results of the predictions in the test dataset
Y_test_traInv = scaler_standardized_Y.inverse_transform(Y_test)
Y_pred_traInv = scaler_standardized_Y.inverse_transform(Y_pred)


#  Calculate the error in the test dataset
rms = mean_squared_error(Y_test_traInv, Y_pred_traInv, squared=True)
mape = mean_absolute_percentage_error(Y_test_traInv, Y_pred_traInv)

print("Evaluation with the test data")
print("Root Mean Squarred Error: ", rms)
print("Mean Absolute Percentage Error:", mape)


#Plot training results
plt.plot(history.history['mean_absolute_percentage_error'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_mean_absolute_percentage_error'])
plt.title('Mean absolute percentage errror')
plt.ylabel('Mean absolute percentage errror')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'val'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()

plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'])
plt.title('Loss function')
plt.ylabel('Mean squared Error')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'val'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

Here is the data that I use (input features and output labels): https://filetransfer.io/data-package/ldU9KENV#link

I also tried it with batch normalization but this led to overall worse results. And I also played around with the number of layer, neurons, batchsize etc., but the problem remains the same or the results become way worse.

Now my question is how can this be explained. As far as I understand artifical neural networks, the networks adjusts its weight during the training such that it can explain the training dataset as well as possible. But if the training and validation dataset have the same distribution and the same correlation between input and outputs, as in my case, a model capable of explaining the traning dataset should also be able to explain the validation dataset which is not the case here. As the training and validation dataset have the same distribution, overfitting can't be the reason.

Answer (score 0):

I went through the training and validation distributions of the 13 features that you have provided. But note that those are **marginal distributions** of the individual features, not their **joint distribution**. The term "data distribution" actually means the "joint distribution" of all the features.

First of all, in order to claim that both training data and validation data are drawn from the same distribution, you need to prove that the *joint distributions* of all features of both training and validation data are same. Because it's quite possible that the marginals of the features may look similar but their joint distributions may be wildly different. You could read more about [distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_distribution), [joint distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_probability_distribution) and [marginal distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marginal_distribution). I also suggest reading about [Empirical Risk Minimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_risk_minimization) to understand why (and under what conditions) reducing the loss on training data alone can improve the model's performance on unseen data.

If it so happens that your training and validation data both have the same joint distribution and you are providing sufficient number of training examples to the model, and yet there's a significant gap between validation and training losses, then it might be due to [overfitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know that the data also has to have the same joint distribution because I draw them from the same dataset and I have used at least 50 different partitions of the same data and the results always look like this. I am also quite sure that overfitting can't be the reason for this behaviour. If a model is capable of explaining the traning data quite well and the validation data has exactly the same individual and joint distribution and the correlation between inputs and outputs is the same (as in my case), it should also be good for the validation data.

Comment: @PeterBe How many samples are there in the training and validation sets?

Comment: Thanks Aravind for your comment. Actually I use the whole uploaded data which has 23040 samples. I use a 70-20-10 split for the training, validation and testing. This means that there are about 16000 samples for the training data and about 4600 samples for the validation data.

Comment: @PeterBe I see. Have you experimented with smaller models (with fewer parameters)? Have you used anything other than neural networks, maybe a baseline random forest model or gradient boosting DT model? Could you check the performance using these algorithms?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have tried many parameter configurations. When using smaller models the gap between training and validation data is not that high. However, the results are generally significantly worse for both training, validation and test data. And yes, I have only used ANNs because I have neither theoretical nor practical experience with random forest or gradient boosting DT

Comment: @PeterBe It definitely sounds like overfitting. From your comments, it seems for smaller models have relatively low performance in both training and validation sets, and as you increase model complexity, training performance increases but validation performance fails to increase. This usually indicates overfitting. You could try using different architectures/activations which might suit your problem -- deep learning is not a completely black-box method, it still requires good understanding of the dataset, and model architectures which can be effective for the problem at hand.

Comment: @PeterBe I encourage you to try random forest and GBDTs available in scikit-learn. It only takes a couple of lines of code usually, it's not difficult to implement using libraries. This will help you to understand whether or not you should use neural networks to solve this problem -- usually neural networks are not that good for tabular data as compared to unstructured data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244810/discussion-between-peterbe-and-aravind-g).